# history function use pointer overwrite

Tags: c, pointers, history

```
static char *record[MAXARG];
int recordIndex = 0;
```

Execution code:

```
int Myhistory(){
    record[recordIndex] = inpbuf;
    recordIndex++;
}
```

runcpde :

```
/* history */
    Myhistory();

    if(!strcmp(cline[0], "history")){
        for(int i=0; i<recordIndex; i++){
            printf("[%d] : %s",i+1,record[i]);
        }
        return 0;`enter code here`
    }`
```

Last input is overwritten 
I know why it's overwrited, but I can't fix it.

Comment: _"I know why it's overwrited"_ would you enlighten us too, so we can help you?

Comment: You need to post a [MCVE]. If you know it's overwritten, then you know more than us.

Comment: Please elaborate on the result you expect and how it is not achieved.